# Unlist all NuGet packages but the last version

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, https, nuget

I like to unlist my old NuGet packages to keep my catalog clean. However, after a couple of uploads it's always a pain to remove each single package manually so I thought I write a utility for it in python.

It works like that:

- query the service index for the search url
- find my packages by author
- extract package id and all versions but the last one
- unlist each package and wait one second before doing this (this is a purely magic number, I don't know if it's necessary at all but just in case...)

The `ApiKey` is comming from a json file that has a single property:

```js
{
    "apiKey": "..."
}
```

and here's my code:

```
import time
import json    
import requests

from pprint import pprint
from reusable import log_elapsed

DELETE_DELAY_IN_SECONDS = 1
SERVICE_INDEX_URL = "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"

def load_config():
    with open("config.json", "r") as f:
       return json.load(f)

'''
Example:
{
    "@context": {
        "@vocab": "http://schema.nuget.org/services#",
        "comment": "http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#comment"
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "@id": "https://api-v2v3search-0.nuget.org/query",
            "@type": "SearchQueryService",
            "comment": "Query endpoint of NuGet Search service (primary)"
        }
    ],
    "version": "3.0.0"
}
'''
def get_resource_url(resources, type):
    return [x for x in resources if x["@type"] == type][0]["@id"]

def get_search_url():
    response = requests.get(SERVICE_INDEX_URL)
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception("Could not reach service index.")    
    resources = response.json()["resources"]
    return get_resource_url(resources, "SearchQueryService")

'''
Example:
[
    {
        "@id": "https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3/nuget.versioning/index.json",
        "id": "NuGet.Versioning",
        "versions": [
            {
                "@id": "https://api.nuget.org/v3/registration3/nuget.versioning/3.3.0.json"
                "downloads": 147,
                "version": "1.0.8"
            }
        ]
    }
]
Return: id and version from each version but the last one.
'''
def find_my_packages(search_url):
    query = "author:me&take=100"
    #GET {@id}?q={QUERY}&skip={SKIP}&take={TAKE}&prerelease={PRERELEASE}&semVerLevel={SEMVERLEVEL}"
    response = requests.get(f"{search_url}?q={query}")
    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception("Could not search for packages.")
    #https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/search-query-service-resource
    return response.json()["data"]

def get_obsolete_packages(data):
    versions_to_unlist = [{"id": x["id"], "previous": [v["version"] for v in x["versions"][:-1]] } for x in data]
    return versions_to_unlist

def unlist_packages(packages_to_unlist, apiKey, list_only=True):
    headers = {"X-NuGet-ApiKey": apiKey}
    for unlist in packages_to_unlist:
        pprint(unlist["id"])
        package_id = unlist["id"]
        for version in unlist["previous"]:
            url = f"https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/{package_id}/{version}"
            if list_only == False:
                # we don't want to remove them too fast            
                time.sleep(DELETE_DELAY_IN_SECONDS)
                response = requests.delete(url, headers=headers)
                print(f"\t{url} - {response.status_code}")  
            else:
                print(f"\t{url} - this is just a test") 

# --- --- ---

@log_elapsed
def main():    

    config = load_config()

    search_url = get_search_url()
    my_packages = find_my_packages(search_url)
    obsolete_packages = get_obsolete_packages(my_packages)
    unlist_packages(obsolete_packages, config["apiKey"], list_only=True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

For completenes, this is the other module that I load here to measure the time:

```
import time

def log_elapsed(func):
    def measure(*args, **kw):
        start = time.perf_counter()
        func(*args, **kw)
        end = time.perf_counter()
        elapsed = round(end - start, 2)
        print(f"'{func.__name__}' elapsed: {elapsed} sec")
    return measure
```

---

What do you think? Is my python code getting better? How would you improve it?

The part that I don't really like is the lengthy and nested comprehension used to extract the `id` and `version` of the package in `get_obsolete_packages`. I wasn't sure how to format it so it's good looking and left it a one-liner. Is this normal to write something like that or would you do it differently?

This script works and I successfuly unlisted several packages in debug mode. I haven't let it unlist all packages yet because I might need them for testing when I'm implementing your suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are making multiple requests to the same host, it is usually faster to open a [`requests.Session`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/api/#request-sessions). This will re-use the connection to the server and you can even set headers which will automatically be included in each request:

```
def unlist_packages(packages_to_unlist, apiKey, list_only=True):
    session = requests.Session()
    session.headers.update({"X-NuGet-ApiKey": apiKey})
    for unlist in packages_to_unlist:
        pprint(unlist["id"])
        package_id = unlist["id"]
        for version in unlist["previous"]:
            url = f"https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/{package_id}/{version}"
            if list_only:
                print(f"\t{url} - this is just a test") 
            else:
                # we don't want to remove them too fast            
                time.sleep(DELETE_DELAY_IN_SECONDS)
                response = session.delete(url)
                print(f"\t{url} - {response.status_code}")
```

I also turned your `if` around to make it easier to read. Note that comparing `== False` or `is True` is also frowned upon (at least use `if not list_only`).

---

Instead of checking the response code yourself like this:

```
if response.status_code != 200:
    raise Exception("Could not search for packages.")
```

You could just do:

```
response.raise_for_status()
```

This will automatically raise a exception if the status code is not 200 (but will of course not have custom messages depending on which task failed).

Comment: I'm feeling like a noob with this `== False` because I'm usually _praying_ myself exactly what you have suggested ;-)

Comment: Just one small hint... during experimentation I've found that the `headers` is an attribute and `__init__` does not accept it via `**kwargs`... but since I'm still a python-beginner I'm afraid to fix it in your answer because I might be wrong after all... not sure about it.

Comment: @t3chb0t You are right, it was wishful thinking that you could do it in the constructor. I misread a list of attributes as a list of possible keyword arguments. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Based on [@Graipher](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/206866/59161)'s review I turned my utility into a `NugGetClient` class that can now be used by the `with` statement and automatically manges the `resources.Session` object. I also turned all `if`s into postive ones and while reading the docs I've found that the magic status-code `200` can be replaced with the convenient attribute `requests.codes.ok`.

This might still not be perfect, but hey, this is my first *real* `class` in python and at the same time a *disposable* one!

```
import time
import json
import requests

from pprint import pprint
from reusable import log_elapsed

DELETE_DELAY_IN_SECONDS = 1
SERVICE_INDEX_URL = "https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json"

def load_config():
    with open("config.json", "r") as f:
       return json.load(f)

class NugGetClient:

    def __init__(self, apiKey):    
        self.__apiKey = apiKey        

    def __enter__(self):
        self.nuGet_session = requests.Session()
        self.nuGet_session.headers={"X-NuGet-ApiKey": self.__apiKey}
        return self

    def get_search_url(self):
        response = self.nuGet_session.get(SERVICE_INDEX_URL)
        if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
            resources = response.json()["resources"]
            return self.get_resource_url(resources, "SearchQueryService")
        else:
            raise Exception("Could not reach service index.")    

    def get_resource_url(self, resources, type):
        return [x for x in resources if x["@type"] == type][0]["@id"]

    def find_my_packages(self, search_url):
        query = "author:me&take=100"
        #GET {@id}?q={QUERY}&skip={SKIP}&take={TAKE}&prerelease={PRERELEASE}&semVerLevel={SEMVERLEVEL}"
        response = self.nuGet_session.get(f"{search_url}?q={query}")
        if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
            #https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/search-query-service-resource
            return response.json()["data"]
        else:
            raise Exception("Could not search for packages.")

    def get_obsolete_packages(self, data):
        versions_to_unlist = [{"id": x["id"], "previous": [v["version"] for v in x["versions"][:-1]] } for x in data]
        return versions_to_unlist

    def unlist_packages(self, packages_to_unlist, list_only=True):
        for unlist in packages_to_unlist:
            package_id = unlist["id"]
            pprint(package_id)
            for version in unlist["previous"]:
                url = f"https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/package/{package_id}/{version}"
                if list_only:
                    print(f"\t{url} - this is just a test")
                else:
                    # we don't want to remove them too fast
                    time.sleep(DELETE_DELAY_IN_SECONDS)
                    response = self.nuGet_session.delete(url)
                    print(f"\t{url} - {response.status_code}")  

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.nuGet_session.close()

# --- --- ---

#@log_elapsed
def main():

    config = load_config()

    with NugGetClient(config["apiKey"]) as nuGet:
        search_url = nuGet.get_search_url()
        my_packages = nuGet.find_my_packages(search_url)
        obsolete_packages = nuGet.get_obsolete_packages(my_packages)
        nuGet.unlist_packages(obsolete_packages, list_only=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```